# How do I optimize my query in Oracle SQL Developer (contains CTEs, joins, subqueries, filters and processes much data)?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

My problem is that I can't optimize my sql-query so that it works faster. In fact I haven't waited up for its executing once 'cause it's really slow and there is much data. All filters are necessary.

**The idea**

*How it was*: I had table `a` only. From it I had to load all combinations of columns `tin` and `reg_num` that had more than 1 row. At the same time I wanted to get all columns' values, so instead of using the **GROUP BY** clause I used window function (**COUNT(*) OVER()**). It's pretty simple:

```
with cte as (
    select
        tin, 
        reg_num, 
        name,
        fullname, 
        syscode, 
               ...
        count(*) over(partition by tin, reg_num order by tin, reg_num) as part_condition
from a
where 1=1
    and tin is not null
    and reg_num is not null
    and (isbranch = 0 or isbranch is null)
    and (isresident = 0 or countrycode = 'TR')
    and length(kpp) in (13, 15)
    and (isbranch = 0 or isbranch is null)
    and regexp_replace(lower(name), '[^a-zа-я0-9]+', '') is not null
    and regexp_replace(lower(fullname), '[^a-zа-я0-9]+', '') is not null
    and (
           lower(name) not like '%pred%'
           and lower(name) not like '%области%'
<and many other "not like" clauses here both for name and fullname>)
order by tin, reg_num)
select * from cte where part_condition > 1 order by tin, reg_num
```

And this works. But now a new condition has come. Now I have to take the same `tin-reg_num` combinations that at the same time have at least one `syscode` that is not in the table `b`. For instance, certain `tin-reg_num` has 2 rows and both `syscode`s are in `b` - I'm not gonna take this. I'll take it if at least one of the `syscode`s turns out to be in
`b`.

Btw, `b` consists of only one column and it's distinct `syscode`s (1M rows).

So let's take a look at the query that doesn't want to work quickly.

**The query** *(ta-da-da-daaam)*

```
with cte1 as (
    select a.*, concat(a.tin, a.reg_num) as tin_rn
    from a
    where concat(tin, reg_num) in 
        (select concat(tin, reg_num) as tin_rn from a left join b on a.syscode = b.syscode
        where b.syscode is null)
),            -- returns tin-reg_num combos that have at least one syscode that's not in b-table
cte2 as (
    tin, 
    reg_num, 
    name,
    fullname, 
    syscode, 
        ....
    count(*) over(partition by tin, reg_num order by tin, reg_num) as part_condition
from cte1
where 1=1
    and tin is not null
    and reg_num is not null
    and (isbranch = 0 or isbranch is null)
    and (isresident = 0 or countrycode = 'TR')
    and length(kpp) in (13, 15)
    and (isbranch = 0 or isbranch is null)
    and regexp_replace(lower(name), '[^a-zа-я0-9]+', '') is not null
    and regexp_replace(lower(fullname), '[^a-zа-я0-9]+', '') is not null
    and (
           lower(name) not like '%pred%'
           and lower(name) not like '%области%'
<and many other "not like" clauses here both for name and fullname>)
)        -- returns all columns with tin-reg_num combos that have at least one syscode that's not in b-table
--with number of rows (for each combo)
select * from cte2 where part_condition > 1    -- filtering by number of rows
```

Comment: `over(partition by tin, reg_num order by tin, reg_num)` is not deterministic. The query will produce different set of rows on every execution. Are you sure you want that?

Comment: What? Why? I don't get it - how can it return different rows?

Comment: If you mean their sorting will be different it doesn't matter, because what I want there is to filter by ```part_condition```. What are you talking about, could you explain please?

Comment: better shuffle search condition and try to use index for retrieving data.